Python Script In Power Bi
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Exchange ID;ExchangeRate;Exchange Currency
1;1;USD
2;0,75;GBP
3;0,85;EUR
4;3,67;AED
5;1,3;AUD"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';')

Error Detail :

I am new in python and power Bi, although I search everything in internet about my problem, Its only comes to that screenshot, what should I do here?
Thank you for the response
Answer and solution regarding about the python script and power bi

So the error shows that pandas is not installed. In order to open something using a module, you need to make sure the module is installed in the Python you're using in powerBI.
The Python is by default installed in C:\Users\Python. Yours may be in a different place. In Power BI Desktop, select File > Options and settings > Options > Python scripting. The Python script options page appears along with the location of python.
You may have to select a Python version you want to run.
Once you have found the python that is used: Go to your folder where Python is located, left mouse click on open in terminal.
Run the command python -V to check your version, then run pip list to see if pandas is installed. If it is not run: pip install pandas and: pip install openpyxl. The latter is needed to work with excel and pandas.
See also this item microsoft has written on it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts
